# Is "'cause" perfectly natural as a connector word here?

Tags: word-choice, idiomatic-language

So if you ever wanna talk, or if there's anything else I can do, then don't hesitate to give me a call, okay? Anything. **'Cause** I'd hate to see a good guy like you not being happy.

Is **'Cause** completely natural as a connector word here?

Comment: I think that it would work fine because it just means 'because,' and you are basically saying 'So if you ever wanna talk, or if there's anything else I can do, then don't hesitate to give me a call, okay? Anything. *Because* I'd hate to see a good guy like you not being happy.' It is a completely natural connector, although the form 'because' is more commonly used.

Comment: It's OK in colloquial conversation, as this appears to be.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is OK to use 'cause(because) as a connector here.

Comment: Hi, welcome to ELL! While this is correct, I wonder if you could talk a little more and provide more information to the OP. Stack Exchange sites work differently from ordinary discussion forums and we expect our answers to be informative and detailed.